# Can I render a whole application within another application in Angular with Module Federation Technique?

Tags: angular, iframe, micro-frontend

I had a requirement to render the whole application from another application in Angular. I was implementing the Module Federation approach of Microfrontend considering AppModule as a Module.So the Idea is, the application in which the other application will be rendered will have its own header and the rendered application has its own content.So shall I continue with this approach or I should go with Iframe? I am Unable to decide.